# Working with django : Proxy setup

Tags: django, proxy

I have a local development django setup with apache. The problem is that on the deployment server there is no proxy while at my workplace I work behind a http proxy, hence the request calls fail.

Is there any way of making all calls from requests library go via proxy. [ I know how to add proxy to individual calls using the proxies parameter but is there a global solution ? ]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following lines in your wsgi file.

```
import os

http_proxy  = "10.10.1.10:3128"
https_proxy = "10.10.1.11:1080"
ftp_proxy   = "10.10.1.10:3128"

proxyDict = { 
              "http"  : http_proxy, 
              "https" : https_proxy, 
              "ftp"   : ftp_proxy
            }

os.environ["PROXIES"] = proxyDict
```

And Now you can use this environment variable anywhere you want,

```
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=os.environ.get("PROXIES"))
```

P.S. - You should have a look at following links

1. [Official Python Documentation for Environment Variables](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables)
2. [Where and how do I set an environmental variable using mod-wsgi and django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310419/where-and-how-do-i-set-an-environmental-variable-using-mod-wsgi-and-django)
3. [Python ENVIRONMENT variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4906977/python-environment-variables)

### UPDATE 1

You can do something like following so that proxy settings are only being used on `localhost`.

```
import socket
if socket.gethostname() == "localhost":
    # do something only on local server, e.g. setting os.environ["PROXIES"]
    os.environ["PROXIES"] = proxyDict
else:
    # Set os.environ["PROXIES"] to an empty dictionary on other hosts
    os.environ["PROXIES"] = {}
```

Comment: Proxy servers are always a problem for programmers at IITs !!

Comment: what if I want to add authentication details for the proxy (username and password) ??

Comment: You need to specify proxies like - `http_proxy  = "http://username:password@proxy_ip_address_or_domain_name:proxy_port"`

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error reported by AmrFouad. At last, it fixed by updating wsgi.py as follows:

```
os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://proxy.xxx:8080"
os.environ['https_proxy'] = "http://proxy.xxx:8080"
```