# Django python paypalrestsdk - No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' and ppxo_unhandled_error error

Tags: python, django, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

Im trying to implement paypal with Django using paypalrestsdk.

I followed the code example from the example here: https://prettyprinted.com/blog/1125955/creating-paypal-express-payments-in-flask

But there is this error:
[image]

here are my code snippets of template .html, views.py and urls.py
https://gist.github.com/axilaris/1e6e34ba5915abceb0dbd06d46baf08b

here is template code that shows the button:

```
<div id="paypal-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>

<script>
    var CREATE_PAYMENT_URL  = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment_create';
    var EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/payment_execute';                        

    paypal.Button.render({

        env: 'sandbox', // Or 'sandbox'

        commit: true, // Show a 'Pay Now' button

        payment: function() {
            console.log("payment function")
            return paypal.request.post(CREATE_PAYMENT_URL).then(function(data) {
                console.log("return create payment")
                return data.paymentID;
            });
        },

        onAuthorize: function(data) {
            return paypal.request.post(EXECUTE_PAYMENT_URL, {
                paymentID: data.paymentID,
                payerID:   data.payerID
            }).then(function(res) {

                console.log(res.success)
                // The payment is complete!
                // You can now show a confirmation message to the customer
            });
        }

    }, '#paypal-button');
</script>
```

What is the problem, how to fix it and what is ppxo_unhandled_error ?

Alternatively, whats the best way to implement paypal properly on Django. (I'm just not seeing any good docs on this)

```
Django==1.11.7
```

Answer (score 5):

Your `origin` is `localhost:8000` and you're trying to access a resource at `127.0.0.1:8000`. The page appears the same on both `localhost:8000` and `127.0.0.1:8000` because `localhost` (usually) translates to `127.0.0.1` on your system but your browser interprets these two destinations as different addresses. Therefore, your browser is preventing you from accessing the resource at `127.0.0.1:8000` from origin `localhost:8000` because the destination resource doesn't respond with a `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://127.0.0.1:8000` header.

I recommend changing your origin (the URL you're at in your browser) to `127.0.0.1:8000` rather than adding the header. Or changing the JavaScript around to use `localhost:8000` addresses.

> [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` (Mozilla)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin)
>
> The Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header indicates whether the response can be shared with resources with the given origin.

Answer (score 0):

This is most common problem regarding Http request when the request(localhost:8000) and Remote Address( http://127.0.0.1:8000/) for web url differ.
If you  change your localhost port then also this problem will occured.

try with these two option:

1.Add this extension to your crome [download extension  from here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon)

2.[Get solution from this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284824/working-with-django-proxy-setup)

Comment: similarly we manage proxy connection in angular also do something like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37172928/angular-cli-server-how-to-proxy-api-requests-to-another-server